# Filter a multi dimensional array in vue js using a returned date(month) string [with the use of 2 buttons]

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

[image]

> a.) 1st vue file

```
<template>
<b-container id="b_container2" fluid>
    <div id="Month_Date">
        <h1 id="date-head"> {{ Buwan.Date }} </h1>                    
        <p id="p2"> {{ Buwan.Month }} </p>
    </div>
    <div id="Holiday-Description">
        <h2> {{ Buwan.Title }} </h2>
        <p id="p1"> {{ Buwan.Description }} </p>
    </div>
</b-container>  </template>

<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
        }
    },
    props: {

        Buwan: {
            required: true,
        }
    } } </script>
```

> b.) 2nd vue File

```
    <template>
    <b-container id="b_container1" fluid>
            <thead id="t_head">{{ today }}</thead>
               <div class="icon_chev">
                    <i id="icon_chev_down" button class="fas fa-chevron-circle-down" @click="downMonth"></i>
                    <i id="icon_chev_up"   button class="fas fa-chevron-circle-up"   @click="upMonth"></i>
                </div>
    </b-container>       
</template>

    <script>
    import moment from 'moment'
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                today: null,
            }
        },
        methods: {        
            todayMonth() {
                let date = moment().format('MMMM YYYY')
                this.today = date
            },
            downMonth() {
                let sub = moment(new Date(this.today)).subtract(1, 'M').format('MMMM YYYY')
                this.today = sub
            },
            upMonth() {
                let sub = moment(new Date(this.today)).add(1, 'M').format('MMMM YYYY')
                this.today =  sub
            },
        },
        mounted() {
            this.todayMonth()
        }
    }       
    </script>
```

> c.) 3rd vue file *This is where I display the first 2 files.*

```
<template>
<div class="Home-backgroundcolor" id="home">
    <b-container fluid>
        <b-row>
            <b-col lg="8">
                <Table />
            </b-col>
            <b-col >
                <UpcomingHolidaysHeader />
                <UpcomingHolidays v-for="Buwan in Buwans" v-bind:key="Buwan.id" :Buwan="Buwan" />
            </b-col>
        </b-row>
    </b-container>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import UpcomingHolidays from '../components/AdminDashboard/UpcomingHolidays';
import UpcomingHolidaysHeader from '../components/AdminDashboard/UpcomingHolidaysHeader';
export default {
    data() {
    return {
            Buwans: [
                {
                    id: 1,
                    Month: 'January',
                    Date: '1',
                    Title: 'New Year',
                    Description: 'Description',
                },
                {
                    id: 2,
                    Month: 'February',
                    Date: '14',
                    Title: 'Valentines',
                    Description: 'Description',
                },
                {
                    id: 3,
                    Month: 'January',
                    Date: '8',
                    Title: 'Nazarene',
                    Description: 'Description',
                },
            ]
    }
}
</script>
```

`Im still new to vue and javascript. And a slow learner. And its quite hard since english isn't my first language.`
<s>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed accumsan varius massa eu pretium. Duis et feugiat augue, id pellentesque neque. Sed pretium, magna a volutpat consequat, nisl dolor hendrerit nibh, at commodo quam neque sed velit. In ac velit vitae risus blandit accumsan id eu ligula. Fusce iaculis arcu vel dolor aliquam, vitae mattis ipsum congue. Nam accumsan in lacus eget gravida. Fusce vel tempus neque. Praesent sed nibh turpis. Phasellus tristique eleifend gravida. Nulla facilisi. Suspendisse sit amet dictum nulla. Sed tempus enim eu lobortis sodales. Maecenas egestas augue quis luctus iaculis. Fusce eu placerat erat, vitae bibendum purus. Praesent tempor risus nisi, quis vestibulum mauris tincidunt interdum.</s>

Comment: Hi @pidz, you need to actually type your code in here, will be simpler for everybody! And it would be even better if you provide us a Codepen or jsFiddle! ...but not mandatory.

Comment: Hello @antoni, sorry about that. I just started posting yesterday. Im using laravel and I don't know how to type my code through Codepen, jsFiddle and snippet. Because when I try it won't run properly.

Comment: Put aside Laravel, this is not involved in the code you're having trouble with! If you paste your code in JS, CSS, HTML in codepen you can then add external libraries from the settings button and js tab. If you don't want to bother putting your code there, (which you should to isolate your problem), paste your code in Stack Overflow! the same code you have in your screenshots

Comment: I tried my best

Comment: Sorry mate, I want to help you but your code is split into too many pieces and some parts are missing like your moment screenshot and the last screenshot. So your code is still not readable. Can you paste your 2 files as is in here? If you need to place comments use code comments so you don't truncate your code and obfuscate some. I can't even copy paste to test on my environment. also you need to correct that code in your last screenshot, it's not indented, missing comas which breaks the entire code.

Comment: Sorry mate, problem is I can't paste the whole code, it always give me a warning. I'll try to make it readable this time. Hope to get use to it soon.